# Why my Submit button not triggered once?

Tags: unity

I have some issues for match the string and the InputField.text it's triggering multiple times after `Active` or `dead Active Gameobject` when press Submit button(in this case is "Cek Jawaban").

this my script

```cs
public void Answer(int index)
    {
        inputPanel.SetActive(true);

        inputField.text = "";

        inputPanel.transform.Find("KunciBtn").GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(() =>
        {
            if (inputField.text != "")
            {
                if (inputField.text == jawaban[index])
                {
                    Debug.Log("Right");
                }
                else
                {
                    Debug.Log("Wrong");

                }

                inputPanel.SetActive(false);
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("jangan kosong");
            }
        });
    }
```

[image: Many Buttons]

[image]

[image]

as you can see on the console the first that trigger once but after second time its trigger twice.

Comment: how is `answerPanel()` being called?

Comment: @Charly its on Button

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 ways of giving functionality to the button: 1) via code; 2) using 'OnClick' feature within 'button' component in unity 'inspector' panel;

Here is the catch:

**You are supposed to use ONE of these methods, NOT both of them.**

Because button will fire **all** tasks assigned to it.

So, either assign functionality via code, - it should look something like this:

```
inputPanel.transform.Find("KunciBtn").GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(() => fireThisNiceFunction());
```

Or just use 'button' component in unity menu and assign your functionality that way.
That's it!

If you choose to do it via code, - make sure that you assign listener only once! In your example you are actually assigning new listener every time button is clicked, so those listeners pile on top of each other.

p.s. Also you can wipe all button listeners clean by using

```
myNiceButton.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.RemoveAllListeners();
```

Comment: you are welcome!